# how to detect multiple color objects in live video python open-cv

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, opencv3.0

In my live video from my web cam i am trying to track yellow, green and blue color objects (in opencv-python). I detected each color seperately as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912948/color-detection-using-opencv-python).
so that i can combine the results. Is there a better way to this are there any libraries available to do this

Comment: since i intended to live video processing this method causes enormous amount of delay so it is not good as expected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you filtering each color on the same frame or separate frames when combining? Also have you tried using a lower waitkey

Comment: It might be an issue with the way you're combining the thresholds, can you supply the code

Comment: i apply filters to multiple copy of the frame so that each color gets detected separately and i combine these frames so that i can get the detected objects in one frame

Comment: So what is your current waitkey value, resolution you're capturing the image at and frame rate? when filtering only a single color

Comment: Because the application you decribed is not really that intensive to severy affect the framerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10951189/4653204

You can use this and build further on it for multiple colors..

Comment: the real problem is detecting different colors which are not very close to each other. So if I try to extend scale then many unwanted colors also gets detected. also if there are any libraries that perform the method i used in a more fine tuned way it would be better.

Comment: Yes, but you should not create 1 filter and then search within that. You should create 3 different color filters (yellow, green and blue), so you can specify the correct range for a color. Then apply a filter, search your desired object, then the next color, apply filter, search object, and etc.

Comment: Btw, pre-defined functions aren't always better for as I've experienced. If you create your own function, you can get more specific results and always tweak as you'd like..

Comment: it is how i did initially but combining them is what takes more time and since i am trying to process live video this delay is very high above acceptable value. I am trying to track the object not just detect it.

Comment: Well.. I also have a color filtering live tracking kind of application which unfortunately works at 4 / 5 frames per second at 1080p. Kind of the best I could get out of it. You'd need some bad-ass multi core processing power to get to +- 27 f/p.s.  Orrrr maybe, process it with CUDA, using the graphical card processing power. You'll get some massive improvements. But real real-time? "Maybe".  My graphical card isn't supported by OpenCV, but maybe you'll have better luck. Search youtube for: CUDA opencv. You'll get some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
ret, frame = cam.read()

lower = np.array([0, 50, 50])
high = np.array([5, 255, 255])
lower2 = np.array([170, 50, 50])
high2 = np.array([180, 255, 255])

first = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, high)
second = cv.inRange(hsv, lower2, high2)

both = first + second
img = cv.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=both)
```

the `both` mask will contain the mask for both the colors.